# Is it valid to sign a Java war file and include the MANIFEST.MF in <war root>/META-INF

Tags: java, servlets, java-web-start

I am looking to sign a war file for distribution via Java Web Start.

As I understand it, the jar signer tool ignores the contents of the META-INF directory so that the signing process does not change the digest value of the jar file.

Will this same process work for a war file? I've never used a META-INF directory in the root of a war file, and I'm not sure it is legal to do so.

Even if it is, will this be accepted by the Webstart security manager as a properly signed file?

Thanks in advance,

Rob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jarsigner doesn't ignore the whole META-INF directory. Following files are not included in  the signature,

- META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
- META-INF/SIG-*
- META-INF/*.SF
- META-INF/*.DSA
- META-INF/*.RSA

It doesn't know anything about WAR. If you sign the WAR, it will be treated as JAR so all the rules will apply.

It's perfectly legal to have a META-INF in the root of WAR. That's where context.xml resides.

I don't even know Web Start supports WAR. It sounds like you are trying to deploy web servers using Web Start. That's an interesting idea.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't matter if app server support or not signed wars or ears. As long as you deploy ear it will work. If you alter ear in a way that it offends the signature, then java.security exception will happen and you ear (or war) won't be launched by application server due the plain java.security exception.

This was tested on WebLogic 12g, but due to nature of mechanism which relies on java (not J2EE container) I am convinced it applies to all app servers.